# Pandas Spit DataFrame on Column-Specific Conditions and Create Column with Split Reason

Tags: python, pandas

I am scrubbing data and have a set of valid values for columns that contain enumerated data.  So I want to split the data set into rows that are AOK and rows that contain invalid column data.  The trick is that the rows with invalid column data need to populate a special column with a list of column names that were invalid for that row.

For example, given the following table:

```
      A      B  C   D
 0  foo    one  0   0
 1  bar    one  1   2
 2  foo    two  2   4
 3  bar  three  3   6
 4  foo    two  4   8
 5  bar    two  5  10
 6  foo    one  6  12
 7  foo  three  7  14
```

with the limit that col A can be {'foo'} and col B can be {'one', 'two'}.  The output dataframes should be as follows:

Valid rows:

```
      A      B  C   D
 0  foo    one  0   0
 2  foo    two  2   4
 4  foo    two  4   8
 6  foo    one  6  12
```

Invalid rows:

```
      A      B  C   D  Exception
 1  bar    one  1   2   A
 3  bar  three  3   6   A, B
 5  bar    two  5  10   A
```

As a Pandas newcomer I went about this as follows:

```
columnBounds = {'A' : {'foo'}, 'B':{'one', 'two'}}
df['exception'] = ''
for columnName, bounds in columnBounds.iteritems():
    idlist = df[~df.columnName.isin(bounds)].index.tolist()
    for ix in idlist:
        if df.loc[ix, 'exception'] == '':
            df.loc[ix, 'exception'] = str(ix)
        else:
            df.loc[ix, 'exception'] += ', {}'.format(str(ix))

baddf = df[df.exception.isin([''])]
gooddf = df[~df.exception.isin([''])]
```

This code looks wrong in many ways, but *primarily* the line:

```
idlist = df[~df.columnName.isin(bounds)].index.tolist()
```

fails as the use of 'columnName' fails in the context of df[] as it is expecting the literal value of the column name.  How do I fix this and/or what was the 'right' way to solve the original problem?  There is also a problem with they way the list is collected though I was unclear on how to store and operate one a list embedded in a pandas cell.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`isin` accepts a dictionary, which can simplify the hard part considerably:

```
>>> good_dict = {"A": ["foo"], "B": ["one", "two"]}
>>> invalid = ~df[list(good_dict)].isin(good_dict)
>>> df["Exception"] = invalid.apply(lambda x: ','.join(invalid.columns[x]), axis=1)
>>> df
     A      B  C   D Exception
0  foo    one  0   0          
1  bar    one  1   2         A
2  foo    two  2   4          
3  bar  three  3   6       A,B
4  foo    two  4   8          
5  bar    two  5  10         A
6  foo    one  6  12          
7  foo  three  7  14         B
```

which can be easily split:

```
>>> any_exception = invalid.any(axis=1)
>>> df[any_exception]
     A      B  C   D Exception
1  bar    one  1   2         A
3  bar  three  3   6       A,B
5  bar    two  5  10         A
7  foo  three  7  14         B
>>> df[~any_exception]
     A    B  C   D Exception
0  foo  one  0   0          
2  foo  two  2   4          
4  foo  two  4   8          
6  foo  one  6  12
```

I like having an empty exception column for the ones we're passing, but we could avoid that if we wanted.

Comment: Thanks for this. If I knew that `isin` accepted a `dict`, my code would have been simpler. Lesson learned!

Comment: Thank you! This solution nicely leverages the tools to cut out complexity.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would do it. First program, then output, then explanation.

```
from pandas import DataFrame
from itertools import compress

# define DataFrame

rows = [
    ["foo", "one", 0, 0],
    ["bar", "one", 1, 2],
    ["foo", "two", 2, 4],
    ["bar", "three", 3, 6],
    ["foo", "two", 4, 8],
    ["bar", "two", 5, 10],
    ["foo", "one", 6, 12],
    ["foo", "three", 7, 14],
]

df = DataFrame(data=rows, columns=list("ABCD"))

print "original DataFrame:"
print df, "\n"

# define what values are permitted in each column
permitted = {
    'A': set(["foo"]),
    'B': set(["one", "two"]),
}

def check_validity(df, permitted):
    """
    Given a DataFrame and a dict of permitted values for
    each column, determine which cells are valid given
    those rules. Amend the DataFrame to note which rows have
    exceptions. Return a second DataFrame that indicates which
    cells were valid.
    """

    # first determine, for each column in the list of rules, what
    # cells are valid / invalid by that rule
    valid_cols = [ colname for colname in df.columns if colname in permitted ]
    valid = DataFrame(columns=valid_cols, index=df.index)
    for colname, permitted_values in permitted.items():
        valid[colname] = df[colname].isin(permitted_values)

    # add an Exception column that for each row, lists just the columns
    # that were found NOT to be valid
    df["Exception"] = [ ', '.join(compress(valid.columns, ~valid.ix[i])) for i in df.index ]
    return valid


valid = check_validity(df, permitted)

print "exceptions noted:"
print df, "\n"

valid_rows = valid["A"] & valid["B"]

# the good kids
print "valid data:"
print df[valid_rows], "\n"

# the problem children
print "not valid:"
print df[~valid_rows], "\n"
```

Yields:

```
original DataFrame:
     A      B  C   D
0  foo    one  0   0
1  bar    one  1   2
2  foo    two  2   4
3  bar  three  3   6
4  foo    two  4   8
5  bar    two  5  10
6  foo    one  6  12
7  foo  three  7  14

exceptions noted:
     A      B  C   D Exception
0  foo    one  0   0
1  bar    one  1   2         A
2  foo    two  2   4
3  bar  three  3   6      A, B
4  foo    two  4   8
5  bar    two  5  10         A
6  foo    one  6  12
7  foo  three  7  14         B

valid data:
     A    B  C   D Exception
0  foo  one  0   0
2  foo  two  2   4
4  foo  two  4   8
6  foo  one  6  12

not valid:
     A      B  C   D Exception
1  bar    one  1   2         A
3  bar  three  3   6      A, B
5  bar    two  5  10         A
7  foo  three  7  14         B
```

The `check_validity` function is the key to the operation. It looks at each column, using the `isin` method to test for set membership. It constructs a second `DataFrame`, `valid`, to record which cells pass or fail the test. It then uses the very handy `itertools.compress` to choose just the column names that `pandas` awesome selection function (`~valid.ix[rownumber]`) to pull out "items that aren't valid on this row" and join them. Collect that list of not valid items per row across the entire `DataFrame`, and we're home.

Comment: Looks right.  I have the 'permitted' dict but left it out for simplicity, but I'll add that back for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

`~df.columnName.isin(bounds)`returns a boolean value (True,False). You need to do the check first and then add your ids. Depending on how you read in the data, you could go through the rows and and check for your exceptions and add them; or you read them into a different dataframe to get your two dataframes.

Comment: Repeating back: first run ~df.columnName.isin(bounds) to get a dataframe with the T/F values together with an index column identical to the original dataframe.  Then use the index column in the derived dataframe to reach the exception column in the original dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that works:

```
import pandas as pd

def set_exception(row, col):
    if row['Exception'] is None:
        row['Exception'] = [col]
    else:
        row['Exception'].append(col)


def f(row, allowed_col_vals):
    for col in row.keys():
        if col in allowed_col_vals:
            if row[col] not in allowed_col_vals[col]:
                set_exception(row, col)
    return row


allowed_col_vals = {
    'A': ['foo'],
    'B': ['one', 'two']
}

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df['Exception'] = None
# apply f to each row of df
df = df.apply(f, axis=1, args=(allowed_col_vals,))
# df['Exception'] is a Series and map applies the function element-wise
valid_rows = df[df['Exception'].map(lambda x: not bool(x))]
invalid_rows = df[df['Exception'].map(bool)]
```

with output as:

```
# valid rows:
     A    B  C   D Exception
0  foo  one  0   0      None
2  foo  two  2   4      None
4  foo  two  4   8      None
6  foo  one  6  12      None

# invalid rows:    
     A      B  C   D Exception
1  bar    one  1   2       [A]
3  bar  three  3   6    [A, B]
5  bar    two  5  10       [A]
7  foo  three  7  14       [B]
```

Comment: Looks great. The only problem is that f() inlines the column names.  Is there way do this where the column names are not explicitly defined in the code?

Comment: For a series `row`, all the columns are stored in `row.keys()`, so you could loop through `row.keys()` and deal with each column accordingly.

Comment: The keys, we have.  The problematic lines are 'row.A != 'foo' and 'row.B not in ['one', 'two']' as this encodes the column names A and B into the source code vs pulling them from an external source.

Comment: see the revised code for how to handle `row.keys()`, don't forget to pass `allowed_col_vals` to `df.apply()` then.